AuthorizationCodeCredential.get_token failed: Session.request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'client_secret'
I am using azure identity AuthorizationCodeCredential with graph python sdk. When i make a graph request after 1 hour from authorization that is after access token expiry I get this error. There is some issue in getting access token from refresh token. I am using confidential client app and a web app authorization code flow.
    @app.post('/callback',status_code=201)
async def auth_code_callback(code:Annotated[str,Form()]):     
    global graph_client,credentials     

    scopes = ['offline_access','Files.Read','User.Read']

    credentials = AuthorizationCodeCredential(
        client_id='7dddfa04-a853-47cd-8c92-d9b657992cec',
        tenant_id='common',
        authorization_code=code,
        redirect_uri='http://localhost:3000/callback',  
        client_secret='ynL8Q~L2qmt1y04ZBgA1h_h9_nlPiS4kqE46hac2'
        )
    
    graph_client = GraphServiceClient(credentials=credentials,scopes=scopes)

    return {'message':'Authorization successful'}


@app.get('/callback',status_code=200,response_model=Error)
async def error_handler_callback(response:Response,error:str|None=None,error_description:str|None=None):
    if(error):
        response.status_code=401
        return {'error':error,'error_description':error_description}
    
@app.get('/drive/root/children')
async def get_drive_children():
    if(graph_client):
        drives=await graph_client.drives.get()
        if drives and drives.value:
                drive_id=drives.value[0].id 
        else:

As you can see I have made api so whenever the access token gets expired the graph client should itself get the refresh token from authcodecredential.

I tried the below code to get an access token with a refresh token after an expiration of 1 hour using the Authorization code.
Code :
main.py :
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse, JSONResponse
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
import httpx
from pydantic import BaseModel
import time

app = FastAPI()
token_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token'
client_id = '<client_ID>'
client_secret = '<client_secret>'
redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8000/callback'  
class TokenResponse(BaseModel):
    access_token: str
    expires_in: int
    refresh_token: str
refresh_token: str = ""
access_token: str = ""
token_expiration: int = 0
scopes = ['offline_access', 'User.Read']
@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def root():
    scope = ' '.join(scopes)
    auth_url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&response_type=code&scope=offline_access%20User.Read'
    return f"Authorization URL: <a href='{auth_url}'>{auth_url}</a>"
@app.get("/callback")
async def callback(code: str):
    if not code:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Authorization code is missing.")
    token_params = {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret,
        'code': code,
        'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
        'scope': ' '.join(scopes)
    }
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.post(token_url, data=token_params)
        response_data = response.json()
    global refresh_token, access_token, token_expiration
    refresh_token = response_data.get('refresh_token')
    access_token = response_data['access_token']
    token_expiration = int(time.time()) + 3600  
    minimal_response = {
        "refresh_token": refresh_token,
        "access_token": access_token,
        "expires_in": 3600
    }
    return JSONResponse(content=minimal_response)
@app.get("/refresh-token")
async def refresh_token_endpoint():
    if not refresh_token:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Refresh token is missing.")
    global access_token, token_expiration
    if token_expiration > int(time.time()):
        return JSONResponse(content={"access_token": access_token})
    token_params = {
        'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret,
        'refresh_token': refresh_token,
        'scope': ' '.join(scopes)
    }
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.post(token_url, data=token_params)
        response_data = response.json()
    access_token = response_data['access_token']
    token_expiration = int(time.time()) + 3600  
    return JSONResponse(content={"access_token": access_token})
@app.middleware("http")
async def check_access_token(request: Request, call_next):
    global access_token, token_expiration

    if access_token and token_expiration <= int(time.time()):
        await refresh_token_endpoint()
    request.state.access_token = access_token
    response = await call_next(request)
    return response

requirements.txt :
fastapi
httpx
uvicorn

I added the below URLs in the Azure AD app's redirect URI as a Single-page application and Web as below,
http://localhost:8000/


http://localhost:8000/callback


Browser Output :
I got the below output with the above code and clicked on Authorization URL as below,

It redirected me to select my account for login as below,

After successfully logging in, I got the refresh token with the access token below,

Then, I redirected to the URL below and got the same access token as below,
http://localhost:8000/refresh-token


After 1 hour, I refreshed the page and got the new access token as below.

VS code Output :
uvicorn main:app --reload


